# How do I pass a dataset attribute dynamically using user input?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, custom-data-attribute

I have a text input box where a user inputs what data-* they want to look for in the DOM. I get this user input on a button click then do a little bit of parsing. How would I get the value of the entered text to be the final part of the HTMLElement.dataset selector?

```
//HTML for text input
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="specificSelector">Specific Selector</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="specificSelector" placeholder="Enter the specific selector here">
</div>
<p id="a"></p>

//JavaScript
var specificSelector = document.getElementById("specificSelector").value;
var a = document.getElementById("a"); // Test element
var parsedSelector = specificSelector.match(/data-(.*)/)[1];
console.log("Parsed selector: ", parsedSelector);

//I need to pass the value of the parsedSelector to the below line
var aData = a.dataset.parsedSelector;
console.log("aData: ", aData);
```

I have read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) from MDN Developers but can't figure it out. It looks like you have to pass the data attribute in camel case but might not be able to do it via a variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is `a` defined?

Comment: What is `a`? Another element?

Comment: Yes, it was another element I failed to include in the example. I added it in there now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need to access an object property via a variable, you need to use array-bracket syntax.

In the example below, type "data-test" into the text box and then hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

```js
// Get a reference to the input
var specificSelector = document.getElementById("specificSelector");

var a = document.getElementById("a"); // Test element

// Set up an event handler for when the data is changed and the 
// input loses focus
specificSelector.addEventListener("change", function(){
  // Extract the custom name portion of the data- attribute
  var parsedSelector = specificSelector.value.match(/data-(.*)/)[1];
  console.log("Parsed selector: ", parsedSelector);

  // Pass the string (stored in the variable) into the dataset object
  // of another element to look up the object key.
  var aData = a.dataset[parsedSelector];
  console.log("aData: ", aData);
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="specificSelector">Specific Selector</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="specificSelector" placeholder="Enter the specific selector here">
</div>
<div id="a" data-test="test2"></div>
```

Comment: Much thanks! That worked like a charm, can't believe I forgot to use array-bracket syntax. Thanks!